# Building a very simple vending machine in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a vending machine with only one drink option that calculates the money inserted and memorises what was inserted and asks for the remaining money to be inserted...and if for example the money inserted still wasn't enough continues to ask and update the remaining until the price of the drink is reached...

Im nearly there, but somehow need to add a bit of code so the program memorises and keeps updating as new values are inserted until reaches the drink price

Any help would be really appreciated!!!

here's my code:

```
def main():
    insert = int(input("Insert one coin at a time: ").strip())


    coke = 50
    total = coke - insert

    while insert < coke:
        print("Amount due: ", total)
        return
    if insert == coke:
        print("Change Owed: ", total)
        return
    else:
        print("Please insert the correct amount of: ", coke)


main()
```

Comment: That's not the way to build a `while` loop. You never change your loop variable `total`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started by putting the variables first, then an infinite while loop exiting only when the amount is fulfilled `Inserted == Coke` while making sure to giveaway any change in case the amount inserted is superior to the price of the coke `Inserted > Coke`.

```py
def main():
    #Settings
    Inserted = 0
    Coke = 50

    while True:
        Inserted += int(input("Insert one coin at a time: "))
        if Inserted > Coke:
            print(f"Giving away {Inserted - Coke} as change ...")
            break # Exiting the while loop
        elif Inserted == Coke:
            print("Enjoy your coke")
            break #Exiting the while loop
        else:
            print(f"You have inserted {Inserted}c")
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Use `break` to exit the loop

Comment: Looks good and clean... 2 questions if I may, does that make a difference? I mean, doing all the variables outside the loop compared to some inside, others outside the loop? Or is just to better organise the code? Also, what does the last if before calling back the main function do? Many thanks

Comment: _> for the first question._
It's for organisation, which i believe is very important especially during team projects, it makes your code like clearer, and avoids confusion.

_>Second question_
it's to check whether you are executing the code or importing it using `import` syntax.

Comment: @AndreCastro check this for more info https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html

Comment: Thanks a lot... Just one detail... is there a way i can add to the if else statement to accept an invalid entry? say a string for example? instead of throwing an error?

Comment: @AndreCastro 
for first question I didn't quite understand btw.

Comment: _>Thanks a lot... Just one detail... is there a way i can add to the if else statement to accept an invalid entry? say a string for example? instead of throwing an error?_

Thats called error handling also know exception handling in this case we use `try: except [Exception_type]:` https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html

Comment: for example if i input "30" instead of 30...to make it accept the string and display a message...instead of throwing an error

Comment: yeah thats called error handling in that case you will `try: [Code Block]` then you will `except [error type]: [Code to execute when error to found]`

Answer (score 0):

There Were several errors:

1. You are only taking input once, you need to take it in every iteration of the loop
2. I think change owed should execute only when `insert > coke`
3. You need to correct the 2nd condition since if `insert == coke`, no change should be owed

Code to be used:

```
def main():
    total = 0
    while True:
        total += int(input("Insert one coin at a time: ").strip())
        coke = 50
        print(total)
        if total > coke:
            print("Change Owed =", total - coke)
            return
        elif total == coke:
            print("No Change Owed, Here's a coke ")
            return
        else:
            print("Amount Due =", coke-total)


main()
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot... One thing that confuses me is where to declare certain variables inside or outside the loop... In regards to the total start at zero, i completely missed that... :)

Answer (score 0):

Everytime that you check the insert with  `while insert < coke:` you `return`, essentialy ending the program. Python does not store variables between different script executions. What you should do is use a `while True` loop and check if the total value is inserted.

```
def main():
total_insert = 0 # this variable will keep track of the total insert
coke = 50
while True: # use while True to create a loop that keeps on running.
    insert = int(input("Insert one coin at a time: ").strip())
    total_insert += insert
    if total_insert < coke:
        print("Amount due: ", coke-total_insert)
    if total_insert == coke:
        print("Here is a nice coke!")
        break
    if total_insert > coke:
        print("Here is a nice coke and money:", total_insert-coke) # get the extra money
        break
main()
```

You use the [`break`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_break_statement.htm) statement to get out of the neverending `while True` loop if a certain condition is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
coke_price = 50
payment = coke_price


def main():
    global coke_price
    global payment

    while True:
        money_input = int(input("Enter one coin at a time: ").strip())
        payment = payment - money_input

        if payment < 0:
            print("Change Owed =", -payment)
            return
        elif payment == 0:
            print("No Change Owed, Here's a coke ", payment)
            return
        else:
            print("Amount Due =", payment)

main()
```

I haven't polished the code but the functionality you desire is present within the algorithm. Hope this helps :D

P.S. I changed some variable names

Comment: Isn't global variables bad practice? As if the code gets more complex these variables will always be there on the global scope?

Comment: True, ```global``` ain't that recommended way of stating variables of a function. However, it comes in really handy if you are using it as a constant and your code requires several different functions to call (when your code gets big)

Answer (score 0):

```
#vending machine
def CountMoneyAndIssueDrink():
    
    total_coins = 0
    coke_price = 10
    change = 0
    
    while True:
        insertedcoins = int(input("Insert coins:"))
        total_coins += insertedcoins
        print(total_coins ," total coins inserted")
        
        if total_coins <= 0:
            print("Insert some coins")
            CountMoneyAndIssueDrink()
            return
        elif(total_coins > coke_price):
            change = total_coins - coke_price
            print("enjoy coke!!, here is the change:", change)
            break
        elif(total_coins == coke_price):
            print("enjoy coke!!")
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    CountMoneyAndIssueDrink()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].